# How to draw line connecting points on circle

Tags: graphics

Consider the list `{1,2,3,4,3,4,2,1}`. I want to label these points on circle the way they appear on list(clockwise, counter clock wise doesn't matter). After that I want to connect same points by straight lines. I am not sure how to do this. Any comment appreciated.

I tried:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1}; 
b = DeleteDuplicates[a]; 
c1 = Flatten[Position[a, #, 1][[1]] & /@ b];
c2 = Flatten[Position[a, #, 1][[2]] & /@ b];
pts = Table[{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/8}]; 
f[x_] := Graphics[Line[{pts[[c1[[x]]]], pts[[c2[[x]]]]}]];
```

But this give lines separate from each other. Also How do you add circle to that? After @cormullion answer I removed my function. Now I have what I want but without labels.

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4};
b = DeleteDuplicates[a];
c2 = Flatten[Position[a, #, 1][[2]] & /@ b];
c1 = Flatten[Position[a, #, 1][[1]] & /@ b];
r = 2;(*radius*)
pts = Table[{r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/Length[a]}];
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, r], 
  Line[{pts[[c1[[#]]]], pts[[c2[[#]]]]}] & /@ Range[Length[b]]} ]
```

[image]

Comment: @rm-rf The points are put on circle in same distance from each other. Since we have 8 values I think we can use 2pi/8. Then I want to connect 1-1, 2-2,likewise. think correct word is label (not mark).

Comment: Would you like to rename your question "how do I label this diagram?" :)

Comment: @cormullion Yes. That would be great.:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A pretty easy solution is to use `Graph` because there you can

- create edges
- position the vertices on a circle
- label all vertices
- put a circle on it

A somewhat condensed form of this idea is the following

```
drawMe[l_List] :=
 With[{ed = Range[Length[l]], dphi = 2 Pi/(Length[l])},
  Graph[ed, (UndirectedEdge @@@ 
        Subsets[Flatten[#], {2}]) & /@ (Position[l, #] & /@ 
       Union[l]) // Flatten, 
   VertexLabels -> (Rule @@@ Transpose[{ed, l}]),
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Table[{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi - dphi, dphi}], 
   Epilog -> {Circle[]}, ImagePadding -> 15]]

drawMe[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Btw, you can create nice things with this

```
drawMe@Table[Mod[i, 8], {i, 2^6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it:

```
coords[list_] := 
  With[{offset = 2 Pi/Length[list]}, Array[{Cos[# offset], Sin[# offset]} &, Length[list]]]
lines[list_] := Line[coords[list][[#]] & /@ Partition[Ordering[list], 2]]
labels[labels_, scaling_] := MapThread[Text, {labels, scaling coords[labels]}]

b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4};
Graphics[{
  Circle[],
  lines[b],
  labels[b, 1.1]
  }]
```

[image: gfx]

It assumes there are two of each label. It would have to be adjusted to work for other cases. I think the labeling function will work for your case as well. What it does is take the coordinates of the vertices and multiply them by some constant, to put them further away from the middle.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4};
```

**Using `RelationGraph`**

```
RelationGraph[UnsameQ[##] && SameQ @@ list[[{##}]] &, Range@Length@list, 
  VertexCoordinates -> CirclePoints[Length@list], 
  VertexLabels -> (MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> Placed[#, Center] &, list]), 
  GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", Prolog -> {Red, Circle[]}]
```

[image]

**Using `AdjacencyGraph`**

```
am = Outer[Boole[Equal@##] &, list, list] - IdentityMatrix[Length@list];
AdjacencyGraph[am, VertexCoordinates -> CirclePoints[Length @ list], 
 VertexLabels -> (MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> Placed[#, Center] &, list]), 
 GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", Prolog -> {Red, Circle[]}]
```

[image]

**Note:** If you replace  `CirclePoints[Length @ list]`with

```
Table[{Cos[2 Pi k /Length[list]], Sin[2 Pi k /Length[list]]}, {k, Length@list}]
```

the second approach also works in versions before 10.1,

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)/[`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html):

```
Graphics[{Circle[], 
  Reap[With[{cp = CirclePoints[Length@list]}, 
     Sow @@@ Thread[{cp, list}]], _, {Line[#2], 
      Function[u, 
        Text[Framed[#1, Background -> Yellow], u]] /@ #2} &][[-1]]}]
```

[image]