# Creating sculptural forms using graphics primitives

Tags: graphics, geometry, generative-art

This is a question based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35179/how-to-draw-line-connecting-points-on-circle/35190#35190) by halirutan.

Some amazing images can be created with this code, and I was wondering whether it was possible to extend the principle to different shapes.

I would like to create images based on the sculptures of Naum Gabo & Barbara Hepworth as shown below:

[image]
[image]

Below is an image made with halirutan's code, included to clarify the similarity:

[image]

```
x = 50; drawMe@Table[Mod[i, x], {i, E x}]
```

My question is threefold really. Is it possible to :

extend this principle to other shapes?

extend this to 3D?

distort the shapes with a mesh distort or similar (see image below)?

[image]

Comment: I think this is not related to `Graph` as you're never using any of the non-trivial layout algorithms.  I'd draw these using `Graphics` primitives only, not `Graph`.

Comment: OK - title changed accordingly

Comment: New [mesh-based geometry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MeshRegions.html) might be useful.

Comment: What version does this work on? Can't seem to get anything from it :/

Comment: Just seen - version 10

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you should not be looking at `Graph`, which is for graph plotting.  This is really a graphics question.

Looking at your example, I see one or more curves split into (equal?) segments, and then the division points connected with straight lines.

So we can base this on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8456/12) (please check there for the code).

After dividing a single curve into 150 segments (using the referenced answer, just change the `/20` to `/150` in the Table's step size), I can get the actual division points:

```
pts = fun /@ times;
```

Find a nice way to connect them:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D@Line@Transpose[{pts, RotateLeft[pts, shift]}],
 {shift, 1, Length[pts] - 1, 1}
]
```

And obtain figures like this:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[fun[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black],
 Graphics3D@Line@Transpose[{pts, RotateLeft[pts, 96]}],
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
]
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Also pts for fun times!

Comment: @ Szabolcs, this is really great - beautiful indeed! I had a look at the evenly spaced points on a curve previously, but was unable to even come close (hence not posting!) - thanks again - will have a go at playing around with your code now :)

Comment: @martin I didn't copy that code over here, but just ask if you have trouble with it!

Comment: No trouble at all - beautiful - really beautiful! :)

Comment: @martin I see half of a deleted comment in my inbox.  In reply to that: for this type of question, which can have more than one kind of good answer, I'd wait for a few days before accepting.  Maybe someone posts something more interesting.

Comment: OK - thanks for the tip! Will do :)

Comment: Nice work! We need some color and opacity for fun :)

Comment: @Szabolcs I have used your code to test but did the following message: `Coordinate Transpose[{$CellContent`times, RotateLeft[$CellContent`times,1]}] should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form`. What does this mean?

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho Did you evaluate the definitions from the linked post?

Comment: @Szabolcs What a shame. I'm sorry. Is Perfect. Now yes i used this link:`http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve/8456#8456`

Answer (score 18):

I have made several pictures very similar to this, using code similar to the one below:

```
MakePic[f_, g_, off_, nlines_, col_, dim_] := Module[{g1, cf, lines},
   g1 = ParametricPlot[{f[t], g[t + off]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
     PlotStyle -> {{col, Thick, Opacity[0.2]}}];
   lines = Line@Table[{f[t], g[t + off]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/nlines}];
   Show[Graphics[{Opacity[0.2], col, lines}], g1, 
    Background -> Darker[col, 0.85], ImageSize -> dim]
   ];

f[t_] := {2 Cos[t] - 3 Cos[4 t], Sin[t] - 4 Sin[t]};
g[t_] := {3 Cos[3 t] - Cos[2 t] - 2, 2 Sin[t] - Sin[2 t] + 1};
(*  600 is the number of lines... *)
pic = 
 MakePic[f, g, 15.6, 600, RGBColor[0.8, 0.8, 1], {800, 600}]
```

[Here is a gallery on my personal webpage.](http://people.su.se/~peal0658/index.php?page=mathart)

[image]

Comment: +1 great :) I've added a picture from your gallery, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks! Absolutely not, I was just a bit lazy to add it myself :)

Comment: +1 Very neatly done. Added here: http://www.pinterest.com/vitaliykaurov/wolfram-language

Comment: Nice to have some colour! Reminds me of nylon stretched over wire frame (check out Vessna Perunovich's work) :)

Comment: Some really beautiful, ghostly images :)

Comment: @PerAlexandersson The link for `http://www.su.se/profiles/peal0658?page=mathart` is `Page not found - Error 404`. It is this same?

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho I have switched universities, and the link does not work, sadly. My new university web page does not support php unfortunately, so cannot make a nice gallery...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Either way, congratulations for their work.

Answer (score 16):

A highly related concept would be [envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)). [Ruled surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface) could be a possible generalization to 3D. A simple way to find a family of lines given thier envelope curve is to use its tangent line family.

**Example 1:**

Suppose we have a curve describe in parameter `u`:

```
pt = {Cos[u/2] Cos[u], Cos[u/2] Sin[u], .8 Sin[u]};
ParametricPlot3D[pt, {u, 0, 4 π}]
```

[image: target curve]

So its tangent vector at point `u` can be obtained by:

```
tang = #/Sqrt[#.#] &@D[pt, u];
```

and the corresponding tangent line (with length 10 on both sides):

```
tangline = pt + tang # & /@ {-2, 2};
```

Draw the tangent lines at different `u` should give us a primary result:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
Table[
      Map[NLimit[#, u -> udis] &, tangline, {2}],
      {udis, Rescale[Range[200], {1, 200}, {0, 4 π}]}
     ] //
   Graphics3D[{Line[#], Line[#[[All, 2]]], Line[#[[All, 1]]]}] &
```

[image: result envelope]

This should work for 2D curves, too.

### Edit:

Another approach (which is basically the same method with Szabolcs), where the boundary line(s) is(are) given and the envelope is to be determined, is to draw segment between two points on boundary line(s). While the endpoints travel on boundary line(s) **continuously** and **smoothly**, the corresponding segment will travel continuously and smoothly in the 3D space, leaving an envelope (which in general is not a line as the above example, but a surface).

**Example 2:**

```
pt1 = {Sin[u], Cos[u] Sin[u], -Cos[u] Cos[u]};
pt2 = {Cos[u/2] Cos[u], Cos[u/2] Sin[u], 1 + .5 Sin[2 u]};

boarders = ParametricPlot3D[{pt1, pt2}, {u, 0, 4 π}, PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Brown]];

Table[Evaluate[
               {pt1 /. u -> 2 π t, pt2 /. u -> 4 π t}
              ],
      {t, 0, 1, 1/200}] //
   Show[{Graphics3D[Line[#]], boarders}] &
```

[image: result envelope 2]

**Example 3:**

```
boarders = ParametricPlot3D[pt2, {u, 0, 4 π}, PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Brown]];

Table[Evaluate[
               {pt2 /. u -> 4 π t, pt2 /. u -> 4 π (t + (*shift*).4)}
              ],
      {t, 0, 1, 1/200}] //
   Show[{Graphics3D[Line[#]], boarders}] &
```

[image: result envelope 3]

Comment: @ Silvia, this is great :) What is especially nice is that you can generate custom curves with this as opposed to using preexisting knot data. If the curves were closed, could the tangential lines join some other part of the curve (as in Szabolcs' answer)?

Comment: @martin I think because of the continuity and smoothness of the original line, the endpoints of the tangential lines will be surely on another continue and smooth curve. Please see my edit.

Comment: You can use `Normalize` for tangent versor. +1 ofc ;)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks. `Normalize` on symbolic expressions always introduces `Abs`, which makes me nervous :P

Comment: @Silvia Agree :)

Comment: Yes - fantastic results with this :) not by my computer right now so will look forward to having a play with it later ;)

Comment: @martin Hope you have fun :)

Comment: @Silvia - there is no question about that! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using `pt1` and `pt2` from Silvia's answer:

```
pt1 = {Sin[u], Cos[u] Sin[u], -Cos[u] Cos[u]};
pt2 = {Cos[u/2] Cos[u], Cos[u/2] Sin[u], 1 + .5 Sin[2 u]};
```

We can use a single `ParametricPlot3D` with the options `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` and add the option `Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}` so that some mesh lines are not cut off.

```
pta = pt1 /. u -> 4 Pi u;
ptb = pt2 /. u -> 4 Pi u;

ParametricPlot3D[v ptb + (1 - v) pta, 
 {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[], 
 Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, 
 Mesh -> {200, Thread[{{0, 1}, Directive[Brown, Thick]}]}, 
 MeshStyle -> Thin, 
 ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[v ptb + (1 - v) (ptb /. u -> (u + .4))], 
  {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[], 
  Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False},
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, 
  Mesh -> {200, {{1, Directive[Brown, Thick]}}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Thin, BoundaryStyle -> Thin,
  ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Using Szabolcs' example

```
fun = KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"]

ParametricPlot3D[v fun[4 Pi t] + (1 - v) fun[4 Pi (t + .07)],
{t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[],
 Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, 
 Mesh -> {200, {{1, Directive[Brown, Thick]}}}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Thin, MeshStyle -> Thin,
 ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[fun[4 Pi t], {t, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], Tube[.08]}], 
  ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
  Background -> Black, Lighting -> "ThreePoint"], 
 ParametricPlot3D[v fun[4 Pi t] + (1 - v) fun[4 Pi (t + .07)], 
  {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[],  
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {250}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[White, Thin], 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[White, Thin]], SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

Use `torus` instead of `fun`

```
 torus = KnotData[{"TorusKnot", {3, 5}}, "SpaceCurve"];
```

and replace  `Mesh -> {250}`  with `Mesh -> {400}` to get

[image]

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{torus[4 Pi t], 
    {.8, .8, .8} torus[4 Pi t], 
    {.5, .5, .5} torus[4 Pi t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> ({MaterialShading[{"Glazed", #}], Tube[.1]} & /@ 
    {Red, Green, Orange}), 
  ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, Background -> Black, 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint"],
 ParametricPlot3D[
   {v torus[4 Pi t] + (1 - v) {.8, .8, .8} torus[4 Pi t],
    v {.8, .8, .8} torus[4 Pi t] + (1 - v) {.5, .5, .5} torus[4 Pi (t + .01)]},
   {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> FaceForm[],
   MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {900}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[White, Thin], 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[White, Thin]], SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]