# Envelopment of space curves

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, geometry, computational-geometry

In their answers to

[Creating sculptural forms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44858/creating-sculptural-forms-using-graphics-primitives)

The respondents showed how to envelop space curves with a net-like structure. I used kglr's answer to create the following function:

```
Envelopment[fn_, pr_, le_, tr_, me_] :=

 Show[
   ParametricPlot3D[fn[pr Pi t], {t, 0, 1},
   Axes -> False,
   Background -> Black,
   Boxed -> False,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[{MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], Tube[tr]}]],
  
  ParametricPlot3D[
   v fn[pr Pi t] + (1 - v) fn[pr Pi (t + le)], {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[White, Thin],
   Mesh -> {me},
   MeshFunctions -> {#4&},
   MeshStyle -> Directive[White, Thin],
   PlotStyle -> FaceForm[]],

  SphericalRegion -> True]
```

We use `KnotData` to create an anonymous function:

```
knot = KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"]
```

{Sin[#1] + 2 Sin[2 #1], Cos[#1] - 2 Cos[2 #1], -Sin[3 #1]} &

```
Envelopment[knot, 4, 0.06, 0.05, 300]
```

[image]

For testing purposes, I included two more curves.

```
noeud = {2 Cos[#] - 2 Cos[3 #], 2 Sin[#] + 2 Sin[3 #], Sin[4 #]} &;

Envelopment[noeud, 4, 0.05, 0.08, 250]
```

[image]

conical = {# Cos[3 #] - 1, # Sin[3 #], #} &;

```
Envelopment[conical, 3, 0.06, 0.2, 300]
```

[image]

**My question**

I want to replace the mesh lines with a semi-transparent coloured band following the curve path. Approximately like in this image, which I found by chance on the internet:

[image]

How can we achieve this - optionally with or without the tube?

Comment: Thanks for editing, @user84456

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ClearAll[curveToStrip, parametricStrip]

curveToStrip[f_, sw_ : 1] := f[#] +
  sw  ( 1 - #2)/ 2  (FrenetSerretSystem[f[$u], $u][[2, 2]] /. $u -> #) &

parametricStrip[opts : OptionsPattern[]][f_, sw_: 1, sc_: 2 Pi, tr_ : .05] :=
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[curveToStrip[f, sw][sc  t, v]], 
  {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
  opts, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#5 &} , 
  Mesh -> {{0, 1}}, 
  Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
  MeshStyle -> {MaterialShading[{"Glazed", LightBlue}], Tube[tr]}, 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint", 
  PlotPoints -> 120, 
  PlotStyle -> MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], 
  Axes -> False, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  Background -> Black, 
  SphericalRegion -> True]
```

***Examples:***

```
knot = KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"];

parametricStrip[][knot]
```

[image]

Use the option `Mesh` to specify multiple mesh lines with different styles:

```
parametricStrip[Mesh -> 
  {{{0, {MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Green}], Tube[.05]}},
   {1/2, {MaterialShading[{"Glazed", White}], Tube[.1]}}, 
   {1, {MaterialShading["Gold"], Tube[.05]}}}}][knot, 3/2]
```

[image]

```
parametricStrip[Mesh -> None,
  PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#4] &), 
  "Extrusion" -> .5 ][knot]
```

[image]

Replace `"Extrusion" -> .5` with `PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"` to get

[image]

```
noeud = {2 Cos[#] - 2 Cos[3 #], 2 Sin[#] + 2 Sin[3 #], Sin[4 #]} &;

parametricStrip[PlotStyle -> MaterialShading["Gold"]][noeud]
```

[image]

```
conical = {# Cos[3 #] - 1, # Sin[3 #], #} &;

parametricStrip[ViewPoint -> {-3, -1, 1}][conical, #/2]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the ```Tube[tr]``` bit, didn't know!

Comment: Thank you, kglr, a wonderful solution. Please add for future reference: Eliminate `MeshStyle->...`, `Lighting->...` and `PlotStyle->...` and add `ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"` and `PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"`

Comment: @eldo, added a couple of examples per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Envelopment[fn_, pr_, le_, tr_, me_] := 
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[fn[pr Pi t], {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, 
   Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large, 
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint", PlotRange -> All], 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   v fn[pr Pi t] + (1 - v) fn[pr Pi (t + le)], {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[White, Thin], 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.2], Red}], SphericalRegion -> True]
```